# Benchmarking (execution time of a for loop): shouldn't we have an monotonic increasing function with the increase of the limit of the for loop

Tags: c++, time, benchmarking

I want to benchmark a for loop. I decided to increment the variable in the for loop by 100 and measure the time accordingly.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <iomanip>      // std::setprecision
using namespace std;

double difference(timespec start, timespec end);

int main()
{
    timespec time1, time2;

    for(int limit = 0; x < 100000; limit+= 100)
    {
      clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &time1);
      int temp = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i< limit; i++)
        temp+=temp;

      clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &time2);
      std::cout << std::fixed;
      std::cout << std::setprecision(5);
      cout<<x <<" " << difference(time1,time2)<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

double difference(timespec start, timespec end)
{
    timespec temp;
    if ((end.tv_nsec-start.tv_nsec)<0) {
        temp.tv_sec = end.tv_sec-start.tv_sec-1;
        temp.tv_nsec = 1000000000+end.tv_nsec-start.tv_nsec;
    } else {
        temp.tv_sec = end.tv_sec-start.tv_sec;
        temp.tv_nsec = end.tv_nsec-start.tv_nsec;
    }
    return (temp.tv_sec + temp.tv_nsec) / 1000000000.00;
}
```

---

## Graph

The y-axis represents the time in seconds the x-axis represents the increasing limit of the iteration.

> Hypothesis: With the increasing limit the time should increase. We
>   should have a **Strictly Increasing Function**

**The curvse shows otherswise**. Why does it take `0.00001` seconds to loop `5300`  times and `0.00002` seconds to loop `5400` times. As you can see in the graph there are plenty of times where we have this thing.

[image]

Comment: There are so many things wrong here that I don't even know where to begin. 1) You're probably compiling with optimizations off. Otherwise, it would be a flat line near zero due to DCE. 2) Signed integer overflow is UB. While this is usually innocuous, some compilers (namely GCC) is known to do unexpected things with it. 3) Your benchmark loop is far too small to be meaningful. For the smaller limits, it takes longer to get the time than to run the loop.

Comment: At the values you are measuring you should expect some noise to creep into the data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Hypothesis:

A hypothesis is an explanation for a phenomenon. Since you're putting this forth before actually observing any phenomenon, it cannot be a hypothesis. Additionally if, as you claim, it directly contradicts the observations, it cannot work as an explanation for them, hence not a hypothesis.

> With the increasing limit the time should increase. We should have a **Strictly Increasing Function**

And as far as I can tell the observation does not contradict this.

The artifacts in the curve are easily explained by the clock's finite resolution: it clearly cannot measure time differences smaller than 1e-5; variations smaller than 1e-5 will show as flat lines or discrete 1e-5 changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can clearly see steps in the curve which means that you hit a accuracy wall in your measurement. In other words the `clock_gettime` call just couldn't give you any more accurate values and several iterations measured the same time value because there just isn't any significant enough difference between the runs.

The little peaks and valleys can be explained by rounding errors. One time you called `clock_gettime` right before a clock 'tick' and the next time it was called right after a 'tick'. This could cause the first time to look shorter by one 'tick'. Here a 'tick' is the accuracy of the clock.